# How to set EndpointReference in WSDL for a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, endpoint

I am creating a WCF service from a given WSDL file. Here as per the WSDL, I want to set urn address in EndpointReference address as shown below

Example of WSDL:

```
<wsdl:service name="MyCustomService">
    <wsdl:port name="SecurePort" binding="tns:Secure">
        <soap12:address location="https://localhost:8453/MyService/Service.svc" />
        <wsa10:EndpointReference>
            **<wsa10:Address>urn:aaa.cc:abc:names:pqr:ddd</wsa10:Address>**
        </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="UnSecurePort" binding="tns:Unsecure">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/MyService/Service.svc" />
        <wsa10:EndpointReference>
            **<wsa10:Address>urn:aaa.cc:abc:names:pqr:ddd</wsa10:Address>**
        </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
```

I have seen something called IWsdlExportExtension. But still checking how to access endpoint metadata and set the urn address.

Any help would be appropriated...

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public void ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context){
EndpointAddress address = context.Endpoint.Address;

var newAbsoluteUri = new Uri("urn:aaa.cc:abc:names:pqr:ddd");

context.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(newAbsoluteUri,
    address.Identity, address.Headers, address.GetReaderAtMetadata(),
    address.GetReaderAtExtensions());}
```

Using IWsdlExportExtension interface, we can update the Endpoint address.

Thank You